# Dictionary just show key and count

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I have a dictionary with two keys.

```
my_dict = {"Hello": {'count': 2, 'distance': 6}, "Clear": {'count': 8, 'distance': 8}}
```

and I am using

```
a = ''.join(''.join((k, str(v))) for k,v in my_dict.items())
```

to convert it to string to print:

```
"Hello" {'count': 2, 'distance': 6L} "Clear" {'count': 8, 'distance': 9L}
```

I was wondering how I would be able to just get the key and the count 
to print:

```
"Hello" - count: 2
"Clear" - count: 8
```

Comment: Your code has syntax errors..

Comment: Change the syntax of my_dict.

Comment: It's difficult to understand your question, but it sounds like you want a Counter object from the `collections` module. [Here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is the documentation for the Counter object

Comment: Sorry about that! I had a previous part of my code assigning the dictionary for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `d` is

```
>>> d = {"Hello": {'count': 2, 'distance': 6}, "Clear": {'count': 8, 'distance': 8}}
```

Then

```
>>> x = '\n'.join('{k} - {n}: {v}'.format(k=k, n='count', v=v['count']) for k,v in d.items())
>>> print(x)

Hello - count: 2
Clear - count: 8
```

Comment: Hello, I am trying to add distance too and using the code: a = '</br>\n'.join('{k} - {n}: {v} {m}: {p}'.format(k=k, n='count', v=v['count'] , m='distance', p= p['distance']) for k,v in d.items())

Comment: ^that doesn't seem to work. Could you please explain how what you represented is adding count value so that I can add distance too?

Comment: @girlwhocodes `v` is the `value` in your `key, value` tuple (which I called `k,v`). This k,v tuple is looping through `d.items()`, which is a sequence of `keu, value` tuples. Therefore, use `v['distance']` and not `p[distance]`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a nested dictionary, you can use `print` with an unpacked generator expression. `str.format` is one way to extract the relevant data from your dictionary:

```
my_dict = {"Hello": {'count': 2, 'distance': 6},
           "Clear": {'count': 8, 'distance': 8}}

print(*('{} - count: {}'.format(i, d[i]['count']) for i in d), sep='\n')

Hello - count: 2
Clear - count: 8
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you right, something like this would work,

```
keys = list(my_dict.keys())

for key in keys:
    s = '"' + key
    s += '" - count: ' + str(my_dict[key]['count'])
    print(s)
```

This would print a list of what you described.